# How can I test an action that handles exceptions using rack/test on Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, sinatra, rack

I want to test this route I made on Sinatra:

```
get '/party' do
  begin
    party_source.parties
  rescue Exceptions::SourceNotFoundError
    status 404
  rescue Exceptions::SourceInternalError
    status 503
  end
end
```

And I wrote this test (assume the party_source is accessible by the test, in the actual code it is):

```
require 'rack/test'
def test_correct_status_code_when_get_error_404
    source_404 = mock() 
    source_404.expects(:parties).with(nil).raises(Exceptions::SourceNotFoundError)
    MyApp.party_source = source_404 

    get '/party'
    assert_equal 404, last_response.status
end
```

When I run this test it fails because instead of getting 404 (my code) I get a status 500. No matter what exception I raise I always get and status 500, which I think is being generated by Sinatra or Rack.

How can I test this case?

**Update**

As I can understand it, the exceptions isn't getting caught by my rescues blocks. Rack or Sinatra is getting it and handling the HTTP Status 500 response message.

I can't understand how my rescue code block is being ignored.

Comment: So what I'm trying to test is that uncommon? No answers in 5 days. Is there anything I could explain better?

Comment: It's not that the exception isn't caught, but rather that you only catch two classes of exceptions. Add a catchall at the end of your begin/rescue block using `rescue Exception` and you will quickly see where the problem is.

Comment: Hello Benoit, you're right. The problem is that the mock object was raising another exception. If you want post an answer so I could mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short example, showing that you can test such an action:

`hello_sinatra.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Hello < Sinatra::Base
  get '/party' do
    begin
      raise StandardError
    rescue StandardError
      status 404
    end
  end
end


Hello.run! if __FILE__ == $0
```

`sinatra_test.rb`:

```
$:.push('.')
require 'hello_sinatra'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rack/test'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

class HelloTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Hello
  end

  def test_correct_status_code_when_get_error_404
    get '/party'
    assert_equal 404, last_response.status
  end
end
```

However, something looks strange in your code. Can you try to replace `MyApp.party_source = source_404` with `app.party_source = source_404`

**Update**

You're only catching `Exceptions::SourceNotFoundError` and `Exceptions::SourceInternalError`, something else is likely going wrong in your mock, which gives the 500 error.

Add a catchall at the end of your begin/rescue block using `rescue Exception` and you will quickly see where the problem is.

Comment: About the MyApp.party_source I'm not using Sinatra::Base so I created a MyApp class with def self.party_souce (..) so I could set the party_source variable on my tests.

Comment: If I put the raise right inside the begin..rescue block it works. But when the error is raised by the mock object the rescue block isn't executed. Any ideas? I'm using mocha